# Text area with Intellisense for web

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm looking for ASP.NET or Javascript (or jQuery?) component for enabling Intellisense for text areas on web pages, preferably the same way as in Visual Studio which is Ctrl+Space.

[image]

The only product I found so far which is remotely similar to what I'm looking for is this: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/wpf/syntaxeditor
But it's not a web component but a WPF one which does not help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should look at [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor). It's a powerful web-based text editor which you can use in your app. Intellisense is supported out of the box.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.